# Text To Speech issue

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

Relates specifically to one event: SpeechSynthesisUtterance.onboundry

Wasted so much time with window.speechSynthesis.  CanIUse states that SpeechSynthesisUtterance.onboundry is supported in Chrome for Android, but the event never fires. Tried many examples online.  Has anyone been able to get this event working on Android Chrome?  BTW, the event fires perfectly on Desktop.  I would even resort to a plugin to solve this if anybody knows of one?  Any help would be appreciated

```
function playAudio() {
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Help me with this code please?');
    msg.pitch = 0;
    msg.rate = .6;
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    msg.voice = voices[10]; // Note: some voices don't support altering params
    msg.voiceURI = 'native';
    msg.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
    msg.rate = 1.2; // 0.1 to 10
    msg.pitch = 2; //0 to 2
    msg.text = 'Sure. This code plays "Hello World" for you';
    msg.lang = 'en-US';

    msg.onend = function (e) {
        var msg1 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Now code plays audios for you');
        msg1.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function (voice) { return voice.name == 'Whisper'; })[0];
        msg1.pitch = 2; //0 to 2
        msg1.rate = 1.2; //0 to 2
        // start your audio loop.
        speechSynthesis.speak(msg1);
        console.log('Finished in ' + e.elapsedTime + ' seconds.');
    };
    msg.onboundary = function (event) {
        /* Never fires on Chrome for Android, but fires on Windows 10 Desktop Chrome */          
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

    speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
```

Comment: May you share a [mcve] of the code you’re having issues with?

Comment: Added code example.

Comment: Afraid it's an Android bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=593517&q=onboundary&can=2

Comment: Looks like there is no urgency to get this bug fixed.  Makes the Native Speech API very limited, beyond the basics. Poor show.

Comment: @MartynWynn yes window.speechSynthesis works on Windows and all Mac products, it's only Android that has so many problems. Google has its own speech synthesis product to sell so maybe their resources go there.